# After upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10, I get a Sendmail-Base Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, updates

After upgrading from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 18.10 I am receiving the following error when write something like `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get install git`. I get this error:

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
git ist schon die neueste Version (1:2.19.1-1ubuntu1).
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 40 nicht aktualisiert.
4 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
sendmail-base (8.15.2-11) wird eingerichtet ...
Saving current /etc/mail/sendmail.mc,cf to /var/backups
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: error: --group is only relevant with --add
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes sendmail-base (--configure):
 Unterprozess installed sendmail-base package post-installation script gab den Fehler-Ausgangsstatus 255 zurück
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von sendmail-bin:
 sendmail-bin hängt ab von sendmail-base (= 8.15.2-11); aber:
  Paket sendmail-base ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes sendmail-bin (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von sensible-mda:
 sensible-mda hängt ab von sendmail-bin | mail-transport-agent; aber:
  Paket sendmail-bin ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
  Paket mail-transport-agent ist nicht installiert.
  Paket sendmail-bin, das mail-transport-agent bereitstellt, ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes sensible-mda (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von sendmail:
 sendmail hängt ab von sendmail-base; aber:
  Paket sendmail-base ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 sendmail hängt ab von sendmail-bin; aber:
  Paket sendmail-bin ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 sendmail hängt ab von sensible-mda; aber:
  Paket sensible-mda ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes sendmail (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 sendmail-base
 sendmail-bin
 sensible-mda
 sendmail
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Before the update everything works fine.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Could it be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sendmail/+bug/1792582)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, thats it. I followed the instruction of one user that has commented at [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sendmail/+bug/1792582) forum. When someone has the same problem:

Only Replace:

```
update-inetd --group MAIL --disable smtp,smtps,submission;
```

with:

`update-inetd --disable smtp,smtps,submission;`

in file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/sendmail-base.prerm`

Thanks Karsten Koop!